# call a chef variable/attributes in recipe which is defined under environment file

Tags: chef-infra, chef-recipe, chef-solo

I am trying to define a variable somewhere (probably under environment file) and use/call it in my recipe so that i can get the value of it, and if i change the environment file (have defined same variable with different value) then i can use the same recipe with different value of variables (defined under environment)

can some one help me to understand how to define a variable/attributes under  environment and then how to call it in a recipe file

I have tried to define the attributes under environment file as below

```
"DB_IP":"xx.xx.xx.XX","BOX_NAME":"AIX2Wd4109",
```

and tried to call under recipe as below

```
BOX_NAME = json['defaults']['BOX_NAME']
DB_IP = json['defaults']['DB_IP']
```

but while running `knife` command the values are not picking up, getting error as below

```
Chef Client failed. 0 resources updated in 5.975572324 seconds←[0m
[2016-01-19T13:15:57+00:00] ERROR: uninitialized constant Chef::Recipe::BOX_NAME
```

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. Those variables are called [attributes](https://docs.chef.io/attributes.html). You can access them in a recipe using `node['attribute_name']` or `node[:attribute_name]`. Your environment file is not how an environment file should look like. I suggest to follow [learn.chef.io](https://learn.chef.io) to get started.

Answer (score 0):

To echo the above comment which is really the answer:

The way to access those node attributes is `node['DB_IP']` and `node['BOX_NAME']`.

I also agree you should run through the Learn Chef tutorial before continuing, it covers the basics of working with Chef.